# How to extract all values of all attributes in certain nodes from XML file in NiFi?

Tags: xpath, xslt, apache-nifi

So I am having this type of structure in my xml file

```
<parent tag>
    <childtag code="1"/>
    <childtag code="2"/>
    <childtag code="3"/>
    <childtag code="4"/>
....
<parent tag>
```

and what I wanna to get is the  concatenation string of all values from attribute **code**.
Are there any ways to do that via  XPAth or XSLT may be?

P.S. all childtags are named the same.

Comment: Show how you tried

Comment: In any XPath version you can easily select e.g. `//childtag/@code`. To get a concatenation of all string values you can, in XPath 2.0 and later, use `string-join(//childtag/@code, ',')` (use whatever separator you want as the second argument) or XSLT 2.0 `<xsl:value-of select="//childtag/@code" separator=","/>`. I don't know which version of XPath Apache Nifi supports.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Hello! When I am using ` string-join(//childtag/@code, ',') ` 
I am getting   ` string can not be cast to javax.xml ` error. Does that mean my nifi version does not support XPath 2.0. ?

Comment: @VladVlad, I am afraid I have no knowledge of or experience with nifi, I tried to read its documentation, it suggests it supports XPath (without telling the version), but also XQuery (also without telling the version), where, however, the XQuery documentation has an example using `string-join`. (https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.17.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateXQuery/additionalDetails.html) So try to evaluate the expression as XQuery instead of as XPath, perhaps,